# Recycler View model/adapter isn't returning the expected values after setting them. Using ArrayLists

Tags: java, android

I call initiate the model/adapter here

```
//Initialising and populating the lists that displays the users information.
    numToHit = new ArrayList<>();
    amountHit = new ArrayList<>();
    amountThrown = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i= 0; i < confirmedPlayers.size(); i++) {
        numToHit.add("1");
        amountHit.add("0");
        amountThrown.add("0");
    }

    // Lookup the recycler view in activity layout
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_playerInfo);
    //https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview
    // Initialize players
    apt_confirmedPlayers = ATC_PlayerInfo.createPlayersList(confirmedPlayers,numToHit, amountHit, amountThrown);
    // Create adapter passing in the sample user data
    adapter = new atc_recyclerAdapter(apt_confirmedPlayers);
    // Attach the adapter to the recycler view to populate items
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

---

As you can see there is four different ArrayLists that I create my players list from.

After the player clicks the hit button I adjust values in three of the lists. numtoHit, amountHit, amountThrow set them.

```
    totalAmountThrown = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(amountThrown.get(whosThrowing)));
    //Increasing the num to hit,total amount hit
    int numToIncreaseFrom = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numToHit.get(whosThrowing)));
    int totalAmountHit = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(amountHit.get(whosThrowing)));
    numToIncreaseFrom++;
    totalAmountHit++;
    totalAmountThrown++;
    //Setting new values in the array list
    numToHit.set(whosThrowing, String.valueOf(numToIncreaseFrom));
    amountHit.set(whosThrowing, String.valueOf(totalAmountHit));
    amountThrown.set(whosThrowing, String.valueOf(totalAmountThrown));
    amountThrownThisRound++;
```

I then proceed to tell the adapter of these changes and pass in all the lists.

```
private void setAdapterToDisplayStats(int positionToUpdate) {

    adapter.notifyItemChanged(positionToUpdate,ATC_PlayerInfo.createPlayersList(confirmedPlayers,numToHit, amountHit, amountThrown));

}
```

---

This then proceeds to the PlayerInfo class where it updates the values

```
 public ATC_PlayerInfo(String name, String numToHit, String amountHit, String amountThrown) {
    mName = name;
    mNumberToHit = numToHit;
    mAmountHit = amountHit;
    mAmountThrown = amountThrown;
}

public String getName() {
    return mName;
}

public String getNumberToHit() {
    return mNumberToHit;
}

public String getAmountHit() {
    return mAmountHit;
}

public String getAmountThrown() {
    return mAmountThrown;
}

public static ArrayList<ATC_PlayerInfo> createPlayersList(ArrayList<String> playerNames, ArrayList<String> numToHit, ArrayList<String> amountHit, ArrayList<String> amountThrown) {
    ArrayList<ATC_PlayerInfo> playerInfo = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= playerNames.size(); i++) {
        playerInfo.add(new ATC_PlayerInfo(playerNames.get(i - 1), numToHit.get(i - 1), amountHit.get(i - 1), amountHit.get(i - 1)));

    }

    return playerInfo;
}
```

You can see this does this successfully through the differnces displayed here when the hit button was click once by `Somebody`

[image: differences]

---

However when the program is supposed to retrieve these new values to display the updated values, it gets the starting values as you can see below

[image]

Here is the code that retrieves these values. This is in the recycler adapter class:

```
 // Involves populating data into the item through holder
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(atc_recyclerAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        // Get the data model based on position

        ATC_PlayerInfo player = mPlayers.get(position);


        // Set item views based on your views and data model
        TextView playerName = viewHolder.tv_nameTextView;
        playerName.setText(player.getName());
        TextView currentNumber = viewHolder.tv_currentNumber;
        currentNumber.setText(player.getAmountHit());
        TextView hitPercentage = viewHolder.tv_hitPercentage;
        //Different form of getString since it is outside of the context and activity have to use Resources.getSystem method.
        hitPercentage.setText("Hit percentage " + String.valueOf(player.getAmountHit()) + "/" +String.valueOf(player.getAmountThrown()));
    }
```

---

EDIT:

Through some  further trouble shooting I manged to get some most values to change correctly by essentially by crating and overwriting the existing adapter and setting it. I've a feeling this isn't how its suppose to be done and would be interested in hearing the correct way.

```
 private void setAdapterToDisplayStats(int positionToUpdate) {

    apt_confirmedPlayers = ATC_PlayerInfo.createPlayersList(confirmedPlayers,numToHit, amountHit, amountThrown);
    adapter = new atc_recyclerAdapter(apt_confirmedPlayers);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);        
}
```

[image: creating and resetting adapter]

---

Have you any idea why this is?

If you need anything else to help troubleshot just comment and I will edit the post.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get there in the end. The main problem was that I was not updating the apt_confirmedplayers list. previously i had this:

```
private void setAdapterToDisplayStats(int positionToUpdate) {

adapter.notifyItemChanged(positionToUpdate,ATC_PlayerInfo.createPlayersList(confirmedPlayers,numToHit, amountHit, amountThrown));
}
```

What I needed to do was to use the addAll method. I had to make sure to clear the list as this was creating multiple elements.

```
 private void setAdapterToDisplayStats(int positionToUpdate) {

    apt_confirmedPlayers.clear();
    apt_confirmedPlayers.addAll(ATC_PlayerInfo.createPlayersList(confirmedPlayers,numToHit, amountHit, amountThrown));
    adapter.notifyItemChanged(positionToUpdate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with `notifyItemChanged(int pos, Object payload)` but the payload isn't what you think it is. You can use the `notifyItemChanged(int pos)` version instead.

You want to actually update your full list that you're using within your adapter.

```
// Initialize players
apt_confirmedPlayers = ATC_PlayerInfo.createPlayersList(confirmedPlayers,numToHit, amountHit, amountThrown);
// Create adapter passing in the sample user data
adapter = new atc_recyclerAdapter(apt_confirmedPlayers);
```

You want to update `apt_confirmedPlayers`, either by replacing the element or updating it.

Once it's updated, then you can call `notifyItemChanged(int pos)`.

For example:

```
public void updatePlayer(ATC_PlayerInfo updatedPlayer, int pos){
    apt_confirmedPlayers[pos] = updatedPlayer;
    notifyItemChanged(pos); // notify the adapter it's data has changed
}
```

You would probably want this logic inside your adapter, that would allow you to call it like:

```
adapter.updatePlayer( updatedPlayer, 2 );
```